error when installing laravel/breeze $ composer require laravel/breeze --dev
image of register pageerror message: Cannot create cache directory /.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache. See also cache-read-only config if your filesystem is read-only.
Authentication has been installed (login and register) but does not display how it should look like on the laravel bootcamp tutorial.
tried to clear cache (php artisan config:cache)

there are other commands that needs to be done when installing breeze. Check documentation again from composer require until npm run dev https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/starter-kits#laravel-breeze-installation
